# Polygon morphing - Keep interior vertices inside

Tags: python, geometry, 2d, polygon, morphing

I have a 2d discrete polygon, made up of inter-connected triangles. In this polygon, we can distinguish two types of vertices: boundary vertices, which delimit the boundary of the polygon, and interior vertices. I would like to morph this polygon and its content so that its boundary matches another one. In the animation below, you can see an illustration of what I would like to achieve: the polygon starts with the red boundary, and I would like to "morph" it, one way or another, so that it has the green boundary.

[image: Example of such morphing]

The problem I have is that while I know the start and end coordinates for each boundary vertex, I do not possess such information for the "interior" vertices. I would thus like to find a way to also morph these vertices, in a way that they still fit inside the new boundaries properly: every interior vertex must still be inside the shape after morphing. The start boundary can be constrained to be convex, but the target boundary can be either convex or concave.

An important note: I am not looking for a way to obtain intermediate steps of this morphing with certain properties. I would simply want to obtain the end shape with the new boundary and the triangulated content morphed to fit "inside" the shape.

I tried to look on my own for such methods but struggled quite a bit. I found [some results in research](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=e07306d83b83509b7f76119b86c8dc7cf1dcc267) on how to achieve similar objectives, as well as results from other users [in other software](https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/morphing-an-open-2d-mesh-from-its-boundary-to-another-polyline/86975/2). However, most research results I found seemed to focus on ensuring that the intermediate morphing steps had certain properties, and, from what I understand, possessed the start and end coordinates for every vertex. I am a bit confused now and not sure where to go forward. Any pointers or reading suggestions would be great, and an already existing Python implementation would be amazing!

Comment: What is good will depend on where points have to go. With a condition "Still inside" only, very distorted results will be acceptable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the algorithm proposed in the paper "Bijective Composite Mean Value Mappings" (Schneider et al., 2013). Their method allows for the creation of bijective barycentric mappings, which means no overlap in the final shape. The implementation I used is the one given in the Python bindings of the igl library, see https://libigl.github.io/libigl-python-bindings/igl_docs/#bijective_composite_harmonic_mapping

Comment: do you have an example implementation of this. Struggling to understand the boundary conditions.

Comment: Is this really distinct from my answer (assuming library is for triangulated polygons)?

Comment: @MBo no, this is basically the same idea, except that the paper uses generalized barycentric coordinates, which in my tests proved more robust to extreme boundary changes.

Comment: But generalized barycentric coordinates for triangles is the same as usual barycentric coordinates. Or you have used subdivision to convex polygons?

Answer (score 1):

For (rather) simple solution I'd make triangulation of outer contour polygon.

Then assign every inner point to correponding triangle and calculate local coordinates in this triangle (as coefficients of linear combinations of two triangle sides like `P=A+t*AB+u*AC` or barycentric coordinates or something else.

During morfing large triangle vertices are changing, so inner points of this triangle should be changed too using the same local coordinates.

Example: ABCDE polygon, point F belongs to ADE triangle with t,u coordinates like `D+0.4*DA+0.4*DE`
[image]